# Positioning not working with transform

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

My functionality is to provide the user to rotate the text diagonally, vertically, aligning the text to the bottom... I tried rotating the text, Even though i have positioned to the top right corner. Its not aligned properly as i expected. Why this is happening when i try to rotate the text How to overcome this.

```css
.outer {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    sfbkshbghjhsbg
  </div>
</div>
```

Also refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmnv62ak/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear what your exact desired result is from the wording of your question, but it does seem clear you need to learn to use [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin). After making your rotation, it is often necessary to `translate` as well, see examples below:

It may be that you want this (https://jsfiddle.net/xtwxxfko/5):

```
.outer{
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  background:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  left:10%;
  top:10%;
}
.inner{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(100%);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

Or maybe this (https://jsfiddle.net/ftgzv2v9/1):

```
.outer{
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  background:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  left:10%;
  top:10%;
}
.inner{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(100%);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
```

This approach should work fine with dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.outer {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
border: 1px solid red;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(100%);
  top: 0;
transform-origin: 100% 0%;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
sfbkshbghjhsbg
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do refer the css code below:

```
.outer {
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align it to the bottom right, here is the CSS

```
.inner {
 bottom: 45px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -45px;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
```

Comment: Dynamic content would be within inner wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

try this diagonally vertical text at bottom,

```
 .inner{
  position:absolute;
  right:-40px;
  transform:rotate(90deg);
  bottom:42px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need transition while rotating, you may take a look at writing-mode which comes avalaible almost everywhere before to be an IE5+ feature ...

I used `top` **and** `bottom` to size the container on the whole height of its parent.

`Transform` is only there to reverse layout of text that seems to me more readable, just my opinion :)

```css
.outer {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; 
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  /* old Win safari */
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: tb-lr;
  /* writing-mode:sideways-lr;could be the one */ 
  
  /* eventually untill sideways-lr is working everywhere */
  transform: scale(-1, -1);
}
body {
  background:gray;
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    rotate me downwards
  </div>
</div>
```